# Is there any way to limit the memory usage of chrome webdriver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, heroku

Is there any command line option to limit the memory usage of chrome webdriver on Heroku? I am running a python script on Heroku which use chrome and selenium to scrape data. But I always ran into Error `R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)` and `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`. As I only have 512MB memory quota, how can I limit my chrome webdriver memory consumption?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519290/chromedriver-exe-runs-8-chrome-exe-instances/58521183#58521183) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466) discussion help you?